# Problema de recursão, linguagem C

Tags: c, recursão

Estou com um problema, em um código que encontrei em que recebe uma string do usuário e a devolve invertida, fazendo isso de forma recursiva.

Porem, não entendo porque a função feita consegue de fato fazer isso.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void recebeString(char *string)
{
    if(*string)
    {
        recebeString(string+1);
        putchar(*string);

    }

}

int main()
{
    char resultado[250];

    printf("Escreva uma string(frase): ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",resultado); // força o scanf a ler ate encontrar o \n.
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);

    printf("%s\n\n",resultado);

    recebeString(resultado);


    return 0;

}
```

alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 3):

O que a função faz é chamar a si mesma incrementando o ponteiro da string, assim as chamadas ficam empilhadas na memória, até que vai chegar um momento em que o `if` vai falhar porque vai encontrar o `\0` que termina a string (assumindo que a string está bem formada). Aí ele vai retornar para a última chamada no ponto logo antes do `putchar` e vai executar o putchar do último caractere. E vai seguir desempilhando e chamando `putchar`.

Por isso que ele funciona.

Comment: Mas, como a função começa direto no final da string?

Comment: Ela não começa direto no final. Ela começa no início, mas a primeira chamada que ela faz é a ela mesma e isso empilha a execução sem terminar, então o primeiro caractere fica esperando para ser impresso. Quando chega no final e não passa mais no if ela retorna e o primeiro caractere empilhado para ser impresso é o último da string, ele imprime e retorna para o penúltimo e assim sucessivamente até chegar no primeiro novamente.

Comment: Entendi!, vlw cara ajudou abeça!

Comment: Eu não sei se você já usou o stackoverflow antes, mas se uma resposta ajuda você pode marcar ela como aceita. Também pode dar um upvote.